# array of $n$ numbers, find the $2$ missing numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given an array of size $n$. It contains numbers $1$ to $n$. Each number is present at least once, except for $2$ numbers. What algorithm will allow you to find the $2$ missing numbers?

Comment: So how are there $n$ numbers? Do some numbers repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a list of length $n$.  Sort it.  Look for gaps.

Comment: Quicker than that, initialize a second array of size $n$ with zeros, and process the original array in order, incrementing the position of each number found. Then scan the new array and report the index positions where the two zeros are found. This is $\mathcal{O}(n)$

Comment: @SteveKass: That is really an other answer, not a comment. Why not post it as such?

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way than with a standard sorting algorithm is this:

Initialize a second array (call it T for "tally") of size $n$ with zeros, then walk through the original array in order, incrementing the contents of $T[a]$ whenever you find the value $a$ in the original array. $T[k]$ will then tell you how many times $k$ appeared in the original array.

Now look at each entry in the new array and report the index position when the entry is zero. (You can quit after two zeros are found in this particular situation.)

The efficiency of this approach is $O(n)$ in both space and time.

This approach can also be used to sort the original array in linear time, and it’s handy and practical when there are relatively few possible values. When used for sorting, it’s sometimes called Ultrasort. [[useful link]](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Counting_sort.html)